# how to manage zoom and length handle in papaya

Tags: javascript, html, dicom, papaya

What I want to do is

1) I want to draw a length on image and want to add handle to edit it.

2) When I want to zoom the image the drawn length should match the zoom level.

```
ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(linearr[i].x1, linearr[i].y1);
            ctx.lineTo(linearr[i].x2, linearr[i].y2);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(linearr[i].x1, linearr[i].y1, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(linearr[i].x2, linearr[i].y2, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
```

where `linearr` is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Papaya already supports a [ruler tool](https://github.com/rii-mango/Papaya/wiki/User-Interface-Features#view-menu), if that's what you're looking for.

Otherwise, see the function `papaya.viewer.Viewer.prototype.drawRuler()` for an example of how to use the screen transform to draw lines, which includes the zoom transform.  Another function that might be helpful to you is `this.selectedSlice.findProximalRulerHandle()`.

Comment: It lets you grab and drag the endpoints, so it's dynamic in that way, but maybe you want to be able to draw and store multiple lines?  The functions I mentioned should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I am succeed to draw different length but the issue is that how can i get handle should i write that function on mouse down..?

Comment: But can you tell me how to draw ruler to particular slice..?